best practice for pagination of tables
my problem is:
Imagine I have a table with dynamic data. It could have 1 record or 2000 records. Should I have pagination, even when there are fewer than 10 records?

A pagination  serve as a label that tells what pg. you're in from every pg. available. In your case if that data you're displaying is going to be in 1 pg. then there's no need. But whether to use pagination or other type of browsing action.
It depends on how complex your data is when displaying multiple entries within one pg.. If it's very complex then I suggest you break it with pagination ,but if it's not too cramp when displayed then an infinite scroll would also

"Thank you. I'm thinking about a user list table that can accommodate 1 to 100 users (or any number, really). I'm wondering if it's a good user experience to display 10 users without pagination, and then show pagination when our users count become more than 10?

I think that's a great experience if your data doesn't require comparison between each other or revisiting previous data, like visiting data on pg2 and having to revisit data on pg1, for instance.
